# Is Using src="// for URLS, Images problematic vs http: or https?

Tags: html, url

If you do not use HTTP or HTTPS in the format for URLs and Images, is this going to cause problems with browsers or viewing?

I want to use the following example

`<a href="//www.test.com">Test</a>`

vs

`<a href="http://www.test.com">Test</a>`

`<a href="https://www.test.com">Test</a>`

Same with images...

Comment: Why do you want this?

Answer (score 0):

I heard somewhere few years ago that this is becoming an anti-pattern because the browser have to do the lookup for the protocol. If you know the service you're using is utilizing https then it's better to use it directly.

Will get the reference:

#### Update

More details [here](https://github.com/konklone/cdns-to-https#conclusion-cdns-should-redirect-to-https) and [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries?csw=1#libraries). Also the discussion on html5bp [here](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/commit/eee759bfe175e850bbc8e4ad0682ec4fe4bd05d6)

From Google

> We recommend that you load libraries from the CDN via HTTPS, even if your own website only uses HTTP. Nowadays, performance is fast, and caching works just the same. The CDN's files are served with CORS and Timing-Allow headers and allowed to be cached for 1 year.

Safety:

> Why bother? Insecure pages using secure resources could just be MITMed and modified anyway?
>
> CDNs are much more likely to be attacked than most of the individual sites that use them. They are a high-value target.